# Как вызывать API из браузера а не с сервера?

Tags: браузер

В описании к [API Dadata](https://dadata.ru/api/iplocate/) рекомендуется вызывать API из браузера, а не с сервера — это защитит от ботов.

Подскажите, как вызвать API из браузера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы посмотрите на примеры, котрые приведены по Вашей ссылке для JavaScript - то это и будет вызов API из браузера.

Разница здесь заключается вот в чем.

Авторы Dadata говорят следующее: "когда вы пользуетесь нашим API на клиентской стороне - то много клиентов могут обращаться к нам, каждый со своего адреса. Если Вы включите использование нашего API на сервере - то все Ваши клиенты пойдут к нам с ip Вашего сервера, и наша система лимитов может воспринять это как слишком частые обращения, и перестанет отвчать".

То есть, просто используйте api  в браузере и старайтесь не делать слишком много запросов с одного и того жде адреса в единицу времени

Comment: Спасибо. Я думал, что это о ботах Яндекса и Google.